# I know views and controllers shouldn't share logic.. but how else can I do this?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, cakephp

I have a controller called `DesignersController`, the `index` method lists them and the `view` method accepts the designer name as a parameter and retrieves it by name.

so `/designers` will list all the designers and `/designers/view/designer-name` will display that designer.

Now if a designer name has a space, it needs to be escaped in the URL. I have logic for escaping and unescaping the spaces:

```
private $space_escape_char = '-';

function escapeSpaces($str) 
{        
    return str_replace(" ",$this->space_escape_char,$str);    
}

function unescapeSpaces($str) 
{        
    return str_replace($this->space_escape_char," ",$str);    
}
```

Now the `view` method on the `Controller` needs access to this so when it's passed a name like "Foo-Bar" it can translate that into "Foo Bar".

The index.ctp view file also needs access to it, so when it lists all the designers it can give links to each one, and be able to escape each name:

```
<?php foreach ($designers as $designer): ?>    

<div>
<?php 
    echo $this->Html->link(
        $designer['Designer']['name'], 
        array(
            'controller' => 'designers', 
            'action' => 'view', 
            escapeSpaces($designer['Designer']['name'])
        )
    ); 
?>
</div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

What is the best way to handle this without code duplication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing here is converting the designers' names into slugs, but manually. What you can do instead is use a Behaviour (like [this Sluggable Behavior](http://cake-syrup.sourceforge.net/ingredients/sluggable-behavior/)) to store the slug of your designer's name automagically. Thereafter, you can refer to `$designer['Designer']['slug']` wherever you want the URL-safe version of the name. This slug gets stored in the database as part of the model data, so you can even query against it.

Comment: http://www.42pixels.com/blog/slugs-ugly-bugs-pretty-urls  --  This is a method of using custom routing that uses slugs created on the fly to map to a particular Model::id value. Better than storing a slug in the db.

Answer (score 5):

The usual way this is done is to put the primary ID of the entity in the URL and have the name/title (in your case designer name) in the URL for keywords/usability.

For example

```
/designers/view/13/designer-name/
```

The controller will only care about the 13, searching the database for the designer of ID 13. It wouldn't use `designer-name` at all.

This is the way it's done here on Stackoverflow.

It also prevents /designers/view/john-smith12/

Comment: +1. This is absolutely the way to go, because it allows you to correct designers' names (e.g. when they become successful and pretentious and want to go by an initial instead of a first-name) without breaking old URLs. It also frees you from requiring unique slugs, which can be a bit awkward if you have many John Smiths (though the Sluggable Behaviour I link above will gracefully handle these cases).

Comment: +1 I setup @Daniels's suggestion, but I might decide to switch to this method.

Answer (score 3):

If this is a common occurance, I would recommend storing a URL slug in the the users database entry.  Calculate it once, and re-use it from there. Why recalculate something that will be the same every time?

Comment: Thanks, I did not know what a "slug" was until now.